# Building Maven 3 multimodule interdependent sibling project with dependencies - dependencies not resolved

Tags: java, maven

I have a multimodule **Maven** project, that contains sub-modules ModuleA and ModuleB and so on. ModuleA has ModuleB listed as dependency. However Maven does not resolve Module B dependencies when building only Module A - resulting in `NoClassDefFound exception`. I would like to avoid building whole parent to make build faster. The only way I have found to get it working at the moment is using exec plugin with script that calls parent project "`mvn clean install -pl` ModuleB,ModuleA" which means that I have to change the scripts every time dependencies change (e.g ModuleC is added).

Is there a way to make Maven resolve the sibling module dependencies naturally (without additional script, e.g triggering parent project build with minimal set of siblings included)?
Does this problem indicate bad project design, if yes what would be the better alternative?

Comment: Can you post some relevant snippets from your poms, please?

Comment: Calling from root of your multi module build via `mvn -amd clean install -pl moduleA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't like to avoid building the parent, because building the parent is exactly how dependency resolution is invoked in these cases.

If your parent includes many other subprojects which you don't want to build every time, make an intermediate parent so you can use it for building only these two projects. So:

Your current solution (I suppose):

```
Parent project
   /    |   \
  A     B   Other projects
```

Proposed solution:

```
             Parent project
                 /    \
Intermediate parent   Other projects
        /   \
       A     B
```

Comment: Can you please simplify your explaination?